# Обновление страницы с закрытой вкладкой

Tags: site

Помогите с советом, есть код, который получает данные и если они выходят за заранее указанные нормы, отправляется уведомление которое предупреждает меня. Но этот код работает если открыта вкладка с этим адресом. Но как вы понимаете держать постоянно включенным компьютер нецелесообразно. Можно как-нибудь сделать чтобы этот код выполнялся бы на сервере самостоятельно, без обязательного открытия вкладки? При этом сохранялись рабочими все функции. Ведь сервер все равно находится в рабочем состоянии все время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения вашей проблемы необходимо использовать CRON(планировщик заданий), т.е вы в определённом файле вставляете проверяющий код, и через панель хостинга(cPanel,IPS manager и т.д) настройте работу cron  (например) на каждые 30мин и сервер каждый раз будет вызывать данный файл, тем самым файл будет проверять то что вам нужно и будет отправлять отчёт вам.
Более подробно можете почитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)